# Drag and drop div anywhere in screen but div should not come over to each other?

Tags: javascript

**I want to Drag and drop div anywhere in screen but div should not come over to each other, if anyone drop div over other it should placed on next possible space?**

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/fv5pjn4h/)

```
window.onload = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        var newDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragDiv' + i);
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newDiv);
        draggable(newDiv);
    }
}

function draggable(el) {
      el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      var offsetX = e.clientX - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).left);
      var offsetY = e.clientY - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this).top);

      function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
        el.style.top = (e.clientY - offsetY) + 'px';
        el.style.left = (e.clientX - offsetX) + 'px';
      }

      function reset() {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', reset);
      }

      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', reset);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the answer and it is working fine now.
**Note : Problem is, i was doing drag and drop by loop, so in that case i was unable to check that, is this div drop location is inside to other or not because that's how to was overlapping and then i made it by HTML5 drag and drop feature and, in drop function i put a check that if any div is empty don't let anything drop inside. (So if anything is not inside it will stick outside and it is not overlapping).

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  
  function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("application/json", JSON.stringify([ev.target.id,(ev.offsetX || ev.clientX - ev.target.offset.left),(ev.offsetY || ev.clientY - ev.target.offset.top)]));
  }
  
  function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      if (!ev.target.children.length == "") {
        var data = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("application/json"));

        var targetDiv = ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data[0]))
        targetDiv.style.left = ev.clientX - data[1] + 'px';
        targetDiv.style.top = ev.clientY - data[2] + 'px';
        return false;
      }
  }
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {width:100%;height:100vh;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position: relative;}
  #drag1, 
  #drag2 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #000;background-color: #f00; position: absolute;display: inline-block;}
  #drag2:nth-child(2){left: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe it’s worth explaining why it didn’t work and what did you change to make it work?